# Database for Orders/Inquiries with "custom" Product Data

Tags: database-design

At the moment i practice with SQL Databases and created a simple Python tool to manage Order and Inquiry with a simple GUI for testing.

Now I have a question i didn't found a good solution for:

There are standard values for Products like a price and costs etc. These could vary from Order to Order (volume effects etc.). 
So i need to save them on a different place.

What is a common way to do that?

Having an extra table for Products used in Orders where i copy all standard values from the Product Database and change them there if the price or anything needs to be changed in an order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, If you create an extra table for storing ordered product information that would be helpful to you.

Make sure you insert all entries in orderedproduct table with reference to order id so it would be easily selected as and when we require all order details with product information.